# UIPickerView select value when View is loaded

Tags: select, default, uipickerview

So I implemented a PickerView and everything works fine when I pick some value, but if I don't pick anything the

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
```

is not called. And I want if user doesn't pick a value, the first value is picked.

So I implemented:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```

but it doesn't work. Why isn't selectRow:inComponent: method called after this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new function to be called when you start. If you want the code input to be read when you start the app, you need to put it under the viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[updateWheel];
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    }

 #Pragma Mark pickerWheel Delegate
- (void)updateWheel
{NSString *wheel1 = [wheel1 objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
aLabelUWantToHaveOutputIn.text = wheel1; 
} //Whatever code you want to happen
```

If this doesn't help, take a look at my project which uses some of the same mechanics. 
http://pastebin.com/WLGq3jvv

Answer (score 0):

```
    [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

It will not call the delegate function. It will simply scrolls the specified row to center.

Comment: So what's the best way to do what I want?

Comment: I don't know if there is any way to do it. We need the delegate to know which row is selected. But here you know that you have selected row 0 at componant 0. You can do your stuff here.

Comment: I tried to implement it in selectRow:inComponent: ut it does;t get called

Comment: As far as I know It will not call the delegate function. May be you can wait for new answers.